# Creating Doctrine objects from a Behat Context class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, behat

**Situation**

I have a Symfony2 project. I want to create Doctrine objects during a Behat test. To that effect, I need to access the EntityManager from within my `FeatureContext` class.

**My attempt**

I have my `FeatureContext` class extend `RawMinkContext`, which in turn extends `BehatContext`.

I then try, as per [the documentation](https://gist.github.com/cordoval/1206686) to access the container, or the entitymanager.

```
class FeatureContext extends RawMinkContext
{
    /**
     * @Given /^I have some disciplines$/
     */
    public function iHaveSomeDisciplines()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $container = $this->getContainer();
    }
```

But neither of these work, because none of the classes FeatureContext inherits from have access to this. As far as I know, only `Controller` does.

**Question**

How can I get access to Doctrine from within my `FooContext` classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject the kernel into your context by:

Behat2

```
class FeatureContext extends RawMinkContext implements KernelAwareContext
```

Behat3

```
class FeatureContext extends RawMinkContext
{
    use KernelDictionary
```

Then you can get the entity manager as follows:

```
$this->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure how Behat tests work but is it possible to turn your class into a service and inject entity manager?

Comment: I don't think so, because I don't have any control over when the Context class is instantiated. That's all done in the background.